# How to select parent rows where all children statisfies a condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables that are in a "one to many" relation.

```
TblProjects
 ProjectID
 .........

TblCustomers
 ProjectID
 Number
 .........
```

How can I get all `ProjectIDs` for which **all** `Customers` satisfy this condition

```
Number % 100 = 0
```

Comment: have you tried something on your own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general solution is to use `NOT EXISTS` with a reverse condition (`<>` instead of `=`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProjectID
FROM TblProjects p INNER JOIN TblCustomers ct
  ON ct.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
   FROM TblCustomers c
   WHERE c.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND (Number % 100) <> 0)
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15af6/4).

---

Alternatively, specific for this use case, you can use a cleaner query:

```
SELECT p.ProjectID
FROM TblProjects p INNER JOIN TblCustomers ct
  ON ct.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
GROUP BY p.ProjectID
HAVING MAX(ct.Number % 100) = 0
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e800e/1).

---

P.S. if you *only* need `ProjectID`, you don't need to join anything at all, just use `TblCustomers` directly.

Comment: Hi Amit, It doesn't work. I need that ALL customers will satisfy this condition.

Comment: I modified the answer already (I misunderstood originaly). Is that still not working?

Comment: What result do you get? all? none? some?

Comment: I get some duplicates

Comment: The query looks ok. For me it match requirements.

Comment: @Amit can you tell why it doesn't work with just "exists" (instead of not exists) and simple condition instead of reverse condition?

Comment: @Kamboh the ask is to only return items where all related items satisfy a condition. Using a positive criteria would match all parent items where at least 1 related item passes the criteria, but that's not what is required. Using the reverse condition effectively filters out all parent items where at least 1 related item doesn't satisfy the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use inner join

```
Select * from tblProjects pro
inner join tblCustomers cst on pro.projectID = cst.ProjectID 
and cst.Number % 100 = 0
```

It will give you what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use CTE to get a readable query:

```
;with 

not_all_at_100 as
( select distinct c.ProjectID
  FROM TblCustomers c
  WHERE (c.Number % 100) != 0
),

all_project_customers as 
( select ProjectID
  FROM TblCustomers 
)

select distinct p.ProjectID
from TblProjects p
where p.ProjectID in  ( select ProjectID from all_project_customers )
  and p.ProjectID not in ( select ProjectID from not_all_at_100 )
```